# Update a column in table only if a condition is met for number of values for a field in other table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out how to achieve the following. (This is a simplified version that ignores/ is stripped off  non-relevant columns.)

I have a table **Item** with columns

```
item_id   product
```

I have another table **Order** with columns

```
order_id product item_id
```

### Here is the problem statement.

For a given **item_id** in **Item** table, find orders that have only one distinct **product** associated with it in **Order** table.
Mind you, **one distinct product** could mean one or more rows for the unique combination of **product** and **item_id**. In this case, I need to take **product** derived from **Order** table and update the **Item** table with that value.

So if the **Order** table has values

**Scenario I**
**Order** Table

```
order_id product  item_id
1        apple        12
2        apple        12
```

Then I need to update **product** in **Item** table with "apple"

**Scenario II**
However, if **Order** table has values

```
order_id product item_id
1        apple        12
2        orange       12
```

nothing needs to be done. **product** in **Item** table needs no update. (It is `null` by default.) . This is one time data fix. Going forward the relationship between Order and Item table will be handled by the application. In any case, product in Order table stays after conditional update to Item table.

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: (i) Not sure, what exactly you mean with updating the **Item** table in the respective cases. - Is it actually `UPDATE`s or `INSERT`s, that would be required? Might help or not to add the respective "before" state of **Item** as well. (ii) Is **Order**s **item_id** being 12 in both records in the second scenario a typo? (iii) Should `UPDATE`s/`INSERT`s to **Order** be reflected instantly? How about potentitial `DELETE`s? (iv) Would **business_key** in **Order** be redundant as soon as it is recorded in **Item**?

Comment: i) It is going to be update of business_key field in Item table. ii) It is not a typo iii) It is a one time job. Basically a data fix. So any future changes to the Order (and Item as well) will be handled by the application. iv) Business_Key in order stays after the conditional update to Item table.

Comment: `For a given item_id in Item table, find orders that have only one unique business_key associated with it in Order table.
Mind you, unique business_key could mean one or more rows for the unique combination of business_key and item_id. In this case, I need to take business_key derived from Order table and update the Item table with that value.` This part does not make sense to me with first scenario. You have two rows where business_key and item_id combination are duplicate (not unique) `apple+12`. Then why `Then I need to update business_key in Item table with "apple"` ?

Comment: Business_key is no the business key for both the tables.

Comment: @user721025 still `unique product could mean one or more rows for the unique combination of product and item_id`. apple+12 for both rows, are duplicates and not unique

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you running?

Comment: Abecee, as I said it is a data fix, so the value of the column in Item table will always be null to start with. It is updated conditionally only if there is a single unique product associated with all order rows for an invoice_id.

Comment: Version of Oracle is 11g

Comment: Oracle version is 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the requested:

```
UPDATE item_table i
SET i.product = 
  (SELECT
    MIN(o.product)
   FROM order_table o
   WHERE i.item_id = o.item_id
   GROUP BY o.item_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.product) = 1
  )
WHERE i.product IS NULL
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f292/1).
Please comment, if this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Abecee, thank you so much for the effort. I Did use SQL fiddle. I do see ddl for schema, insert statements and update SQL. So I used buttton "build schema" that seems to be working but when I try "Run SQL" I do not find anything in the results. I tried tabular or text output, too.

Comment: Abecee, as I said it is a data fix, so the value of the column in Item table will always be null to start with. It is updated conditionally only if there is a single unique product associated with all order rows for an invoice_id.

Comment: @user721025: OK - had a slightly different reading of "data fix". Doesn't affect the suggested solution too much, though. (The `WHERE` just won't help to limit the required processing...) For Oracle in SQL Fiddle, the `UPDATE` had to go into the schema box. Caused an error otherwise. To see the effect, remove it, re-build the schema, re-run the statement - and there won't be "apple" in the **item_table**.

Answer (score 0):

```
update Items i
set i.product = (select max(o.product) from Orders o where o.item_id = i.item_id)
where 1 = (
  select count(distinct o.product)
  from Orders o
  where o.item_id = i.item_id
)
```

Note: I think some of the confusion with your post has to do with your use of the word `unique`.  I think you meant to use the word `distinct` instead.

So when you say:

> For a given item_id in Item table, find orders that have only one **unique** product associated with it in Order table.

I think you meant to say:

> For a given item_id in Item table, find orders that have only one **distinct** product associated with it in Order table.